# Manipulating tuples

Tags: scala, tuples

Is there a way to manipulate multiple values of a tuple without using a temporary variable and starting a new statement?

Say I have a method that returns a tuple and I want to do something with those values inline.

e.g. if I want to split a string at a certain point and reverse the pieces

```
def backToFront(s: String, n:Int) = s.splitAt(n)...
```

I can do

```
val (a, b) = s.splitAt(n)
b + a
```

(requires temporary variables and new statement) or

```
List(s.splitAt(n)).map(i => i._2 + i._1).head
```

(works, but seems a bit dirty, creating a single element List just for this) or

```
s.splitAt(n).swap.productIterator.mkString
```

(works for this particular example, but only because there happens to be a `swap` method that does what I want, so it's not very general).

The `zipped` method on tuples seems just to be for tuples of Lists.

As another example, how could you turn the tuple `('a, 'b, 'c)` into `('b, 'a, 'c)` in one statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tuples are just convenient return type, and it is not assumed that you will make complicated manipulations with it. Also there was similar [discussion](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7516) on scala forums.

About the last example, couldn't find anything better than pattern-matching.

```
('a, 'b, 'c) match { case (a, b, c) => (b, a ,c) }
```

Comment: Pattern matching is good! `s.splitAt(n) match {case(a,b) => b + a}` works for the first part

Comment: It's a pity there isn't a `fold` method in the standard library; then you could just `s.splitAt(n).fold((a,b) => b + a)`, and it would be more efficient, too.  (Yes, of course I've made my own.)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the built-in methods on tuples are [pretty limited](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2).

Maybe you want something like these in your personal library,

```
def fold2[A, B, C](x: (A, B))(f: (A, B) => C): C = f(x._1, x._2)
def fold3[A, B, C, D](x: (A, B, C))(f: (A, B, C) => D): D = f(x._1, x._2, x._3)
```

With the appropriate implicit conversions, you could do,

```
scala> "hello world".splitAt(5).swap.fold(_ + _)
res1: java.lang.String = " worldhello"

scala> (1, 2, 3).fold((a, b, c) => (b, c, a))
res2: (Int, Int, Int) = (2,3,1)
```

An alternative to the last expression would be the "pipe" operator `|>` (get it from Scalaz or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606074/scala-can-a-literal-reference-itself/6606312#6606312)),

```
scala> ('a, 'b, 'c) |> (t => (t._2, t._3, t._1))
res3: (Symbol, Symbol, Symbol) = ('b,'c,'a)
```

This would be nice, if not for the required annotations,

```
scala> ("hello ", "world") |> (((_: String) + (_: String)).tupled)
res4: java.lang.String = hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
s.splitAt(n) |> Function.tupled(_ + _)
```

[ Edit: Just noticed your arguments to function are reversed.  In that case, you will have to give up placeholder syntax and instead go for: `s.splitAt(n) |> Function.tupled((a, b) => b + a)` ]

For your last example, can't think of anything better than a pattern match (as shown by @4e6.)

Answer (score 0):

With the current development version of [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), you can achieve this without unpacking the tuple:

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

val s = "abcdefgh"
val n = 3

s.splitAt(n).rotateRight[shapeless.Nat._1].mkString("", "", "") // "defghabc"
```

I think you shouldn't have to wait too long (matter of days I'd say) before the syntax of the methods of the last line get cleaned, and you can simply write

```
s.splitAt(n).rotateRight(1).mkString
```