# How to flatten a tuple of lists to a list of lists in Scala

Tags: list, scala, type-conversion, tuples, flatten

im new in Scala and im Looking for a way to do something like

```
val list = List(1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1)

mylist.sortWith(_ > _).partition(_ == 1).flatten
```

Problem is that partition() yields a tuple of lists but i need a list of lists.

The goal is to have this job done in one line without using other variable, optimisation in not a requirement.

A dirty/stupid way to achieve what im trying to do would be:

```
List(mylist.sortWith(_ > _).partition(_ == 1)._1, mylist.sortWith(_ > _).partition(_ == 1)._2).flatten
```

I am also wondering if i can cast the output of partition() to flatten it

Comment: So you want a final output of `List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)`? That's what I get running your "dirty/stupid" approach.

Comment: yes, but output is not really important :)

Comment: Pattern matching. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7129849/770361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a missing feature of Scala, "a method to convert a tuple to a list", but you can use *productIterator* to get there...sort of.  ProductIterator returns a List[Any] so it's rather ugly but you could do something like:

```
  val list = List(1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1)

  list
    .sortBy(-_)
    .partition( _ == 1 )
    .productIterator.map( _.asInstanceOf[List[Int]] )
    .toList.flatten

 // Results in: List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Just for a display of virtuosity you could also arrive at the same answer with

```
list.sortBy(-_).foldLeft(List[Int]()){case (a,1) => 1 +: a case (a,v) => a :+ v}
```

or:

```
list.sortBy(-_).sortWith((a,b) => a == 1)
```

Comment: 1. Instead of `map` you can use `.asInstanceOf[Iterator[List[Int]]]`. 2. Your `sortWith` doesn't work as intended

Comment: Right `list.sortWith((a,b) => a == 1 || a > b)` isn't working but the 2 other solution are nice thx

@LuigiPlinge I dont understand yet why do i have to cast to  `Iterator[List[Int]]` but ill take a look at it. thx too

Comment: @LuigiPlinge are right and I need new glasses...I changed the example but alas it's not so clever.

Comment: @mike the "cast", _.asInstanceOf[List[Int]], is needed to get the flatten method to work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it:

```
list.sorted.groupBy(_ == 1).values.toList
```

- sorted() simply sorts the list in ascending order (doable since it just contains Ints)
- groupBy() converts this to a map of true -> 1's, false -> all else
- values() returns the map's values
- toList() converts this collection of the map's values into your desired list.

Comment: Why use `sorted` at all ?

Comment: The original question sorted the list. Or do you mean another sort method would have been better here?

Comment: Oh sorry.. my bad! I didn't notice that !